# Isolation Amplifier Design Issue

Tags: amplifier, isolation, modulation, demodulation

I modulate input signal with triangle wave to create PWM signal. When I am creating triangle wave I use astable multivibrator and integrating circuit. unfortunately there are offset at my triangle wave because of op-amp so I have to add an offset to input signal for smooth modulation. therefore, output signal have offset like pitcure below. How can overcome the offset problem?

(attention : I can not use negative supply for opamps )

yellow----> input signal

green ----> output signal

pink -----> triangle wave(carrier signal)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest you post the schematic.  But suspect the answer will be capacitive coupling of modulation signal plus dc coupled bias.

Comment: Pretty much unanswerable without a schematic

Comment: It looks like you have a significant amount of crossover distortion in your output signal, which is really unusual for a class-D amplifier. It looks like any DC bias on your triangle wave is the least of your worries. We REALLY need a schematic in order to understand what you have built.

Comment: I added schematic ,thanks for your comments . Waiting for your more advice